rollback database in local doesn't update postgres in server Rails 7
I'm running Rails 7 on my server, even though when I add a new table, it does migrate and I can see it in the server database. But when I made changes by rolling back in development environment, and then migrated, it didn't update the server's database.
database.yml
# SQLite. Versions 3.8.0 and up are supported.
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem "sqlite3"
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

deploy/production.rb :
server 'ip_here', user: 'user_here', roles: %w{app db web}

I also tried:
cap production deploy:migrate

but didn't work. Also, when I looked up if the new updated migration files exist in the server, they do.


I made changes by rolling back in development environment, and then migrated, it didn't update the server's database.

You are misunderstanding how migrations are deployed.
In short, my advice would be:

Do not edit migrations that have already been deployed. (Unless you have a good reason, and know what you're doing!)
Do not rollback the database in production. (Unless you have a good reason, and you know what you're doing!)
To change the production database, deploy a new migration.

You didn't share the specific migration file (old and new versions) that this question is about, but for example you might want to use:
change_column
rename_column
rename_index
rename_table

Or you could make the change in two steps, e.g. remove_column ... add_column

Why didn't the production system know that it was supposed to rollback and then re-migrate?
Each migration file has a specific version number, e.g. 20240502100000. After deploying to production and migrating, the production database stores this migration as "applied".
When you edited the file and re-deployed it, from the production system's perspective it had already applied this migration. It didn't know the file had been edited, and you never ran an explicit command to rollback and migrate again.
This is why it's usually the best idea to just create a new migration file.
